# Prove that $1+a+a^2+...+a^{\phi(m)-1} \equiv 0 \pmod m$ if $g.c.d.(a,m)=1$ and $g.c.d.(a-1,m)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am totally clueless right now. I assume using Fermat's Little Theorem or Euler's Theorem.
I feel like $g.c.d.(a-1,m)=1$ will give something but I cannot work that out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$(a-1)(1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{\phi(m)-1})=a^{\phi(m)}-1\equiv 0\pmod m$$

and $\rm{g.c.d.}(a-1,m)=1$

hence

> $$1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{\phi(m)-1}\equiv 0\pmod m $$